# JQuery related Problems

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

How can i write this formula : **(loanAmt((i / 360) + (i / 360 / (1 + i / 360)^ n * 30 - 1))** in jQuery......the code which i had written in my application is not working.....so please suggest me how can i write that.......

```
$("#btnDimi").click(function (evt) {
    var loanAmt,
        i,
        n;

    loanAmt = $("#LoanAmt").val();
    i = $("#Interest").val();
    n = $("#LoanPeriod").val();
    var selectedRadio = $("input[name='PaymentType']:checked").val();

    if (selectedRadio == 'Daily') {
        var result = eval(" loanAmt((i / 360) + (i / 360 / Math.pow(1 + i / 360, n * 30)) - 1) ");
        $("#Payment").val(result);
    } else {
        // some other codes...... with another formula
    }
});
```

Comment: **1.** Remove those two stars `**` from `var result` **2.** Don't use `eval`. **3.** `loanAmt` is not a function.

Comment: no no that two star is the thing i want to bold.......nt the problem

Comment: i tried that also bt nt working..........

Comment: Try `var result = loanAmt * ((i / 360) + (i / 360 / Math.pow(1 + i / 360, n * 30)) - 1);`

Comment: i tried this also bt its nt working..............

Answer (score 1):

Change your lines like this(Note:You can use parseInt() method to convert your input values to integer):

loanAmt = praseInt($("#LoanAmt").val()); - Like this for all

```
 var result = eval(" loanAmt((i / 360) + (i / 360 / Math.pow(1 + i / 360, n * 30)) - 1) ");

TO 

 var result = eval(" loanAmt*((i / 360) + (i / 360 / Math.pow(1 + i / 360, n * 30)) - 1) ");
```

Comment: <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IntCalOpt, new { @class="col-md-3 control-label from-inline"})
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="button" value="Dimi" id="btnDimi" name="btnDimi" class="btn  btn-success form-inline" />
            <input type="button" value="Flat" id="btnFlat" name="btnFlat" class="btn  btn-danger form-inline" />
              </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Payment, new { @class="col-md-3 control-label"})

Comment: <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Payment, new { @class="form-control",@Placeholder="TOTAL"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Payment)
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="col-md-offset-6 btn btn-primary" /> 
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-warning" />
    </div>
}